# SharePoint List/row Formatting

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint online and would like to use row formatting on a document library.

Ideally i like the tile view for the documents. However, it only shows the "name" of the file. I would like to use the Title instead of the Name and i prefer to keep the same tile view style.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use view formatting for the default Tiles style view, we need create following view formatting for List style view.

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": "true",
  "hideColumnHeader": "true",
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "a",
    "attributes": {
      "href": "[$FileRef]",
      "target": "'_blank'"
    },
    "style": {
      "float": "left"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt ms-bgColor-themePrimary--hover ms-fontColor-white--hover"
        },
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "min-width": "180px",
          "min-height": "150px",
          "margin-right": "10px",
          "margin-top": "10px",
          "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "text-align": "center",
              "margin": "auto"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-row-title "
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Title]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "iconName": "Test",
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-su"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Refer to: [sp-dev-list-formatting>generic-tile-format](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/generic-tile-format)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I add this to a list view and i get unstyled grey boxes, is the css not working? We like the tile view and would like to use that with the title showing. The tile view also links nicely to the preview and all of it's great functionality.

Comment: can you help me with pulling through the thumbnail and linking to the preview mode?